# Dynamic display in Grails

Tags: ajax, grails

I have this problem I'm facing. I have been working on a project using Grails based on the advice from a friend. I'm still a novice in using Grails, so any down to earth explanation would be highly welcomed.

My project is a web application which scans broken or dead links and displays them on a screen. The main application is written in Java, and it displays the output (good links, bad links, pages scanned) continuously on the system console as the scan goes on. I've finished implementing my UI, controllers, views, database using Grails. Now, I will like to display actively in a section of my GSP page say forager.gsp the current link being scanned, the current number of bad links found and the current page being scanned.

The attempts I have tried in implementing this active display include storing the output my application displays on the console in a table in my database. This table has a single row which is constantly updated as the current paged scanned changes, number of good links found changes and number of bad links found changes. As this particular table is being updated constantly, I've written an action in my controller which reads this single line and renders the result to my UI. The problem I'm now facing is that I need a way of constantly updating the result being displayed after an interval of time in my UI. I want the final output to look like

```
scanning: This page,  Bad links: 8, good links: 200
```

So basically here is my controller action which reads the table from the database

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class PHPController {

   def index() {}

   def dataSource

   def ajax = {

      def sql = new Sql(dataSource)

      def errors = sql.rows("SELECT *from links")

      render (view: 'index', template:'test', model:[errors:errors])
   }
}
```

Here is the template I render  test.gsp

```
<table border="0">
<g:each in="${ errors }" var="error">
   <tr><td>${ error.address }</td><td>${ error.error}</td><td>${ error.pageLink}</td></tr>
</g:each>
</table>
```

For now I'm working with a test UI, which means this is not my UI but one I use for testing purposes, say index.gsp

```
<html>
<body>

<div><p>Pleaseeee, update only the ones below</p></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function ClickMe(){
      setInterval('document.getElementById("auto").click()',5000);
      alert("Function works");
   }
</script>

<div id="dont't touch">
   <g:formRemote url="[controller:'PHP', action:'ajax']"  update="ajaxDiv"
                 asynchronous="true" name="Form" onComplete="ClickMe()" after="ClickMe()">
   <div>
      <input id="auto" type="button" value="Click"  />
   </div>
</g:formRemote>

<div id="ajaxDiv">
   <g:render template="/PHP/test"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The div I'm trying to update is "ajaxDiv". Anyone trying to answer this question can just assume that I dont have an index.gsp and can propose a solution from scratch. This is the first time I'm using Grails in my life so far, and also the first time I'm ever dealing with ajax in any form. The aim is to dynamically fetch data from my database and display the result. Or if someone knows how to directly mirror output from the system console unto the UI, that will also be great.

Comment: I appreciate the changes you've made to my post. I've gone through your profile and realized you must be a really good expert in grails. It will be very nice of you if you could help in proposing something for me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a form would be appropriate for your needs. Check out the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Tags/form.html) on forms. You should be able to render a form with the values you would like without too much trouble. Be sure to pay attention to your mapping and let me know if you have any questions after you have set index.gsp up to render a form for your values.

Comment: I actually make use of a form through the tag <g:formRemote>, which basically is a <g:form> tag. what I want to be able to do is call an action repeatedly in order to refresh a particular element in my page. The problem I'm facing with forms is that once I submit a form, I cannot use setTiemout or setInterval to recall(trigger) the button which submitted the form. I just want to be able to refresh my page with updated data from my datdabase

Comment: Can you add a bit of Javascript that refreshes the element every 20 seconds (for example) until there is no change in your background process at which point it would stop? The <g:javascript> tag would be helpful if that was an option for you.

Comment: Actually, I think that refreshing the element only wouldn't be of great help since the data being passed to it would not be refreshed. That is why I tried as well refreshing(recalling) the controller action which fetches the data from the database before refreshing the element. But, as I earlier mentioned since the action(controller) must be called within a <form> tag, it seems you cannot submit(calling the submit button within the tag) it multiple times(refreshing) using a javascript, and that is exactly where my code above faces a problem. I'm open to any totally new suggestion